# Is there is an API to push content to the Bitbucket Repo

Tags: bitbucket-api

Hi Kudos past few days iam researching the Bitbucket API documentation, I could not found an Proper instruction and API to push the content to Repo either in raw or encoded(base64).. If anybody know's the API or mechanism to push the content through API plz let me know.. Thanks advance...

Comment: Welcome srackoverflow. Your question is very broad now and doesn't fit the site's topic, please a look on help and try to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Pushing new content to a repo is done through pushing, not the API. There is the online editor, but that does not currently have a public API.